Как рассчитать уровень буфера у видео
this.dsh.on("bufferLevelUpdated", e => {
    if(e.mediaType == 'video')
     this.p[0].style.width = (this.v.currentTime + e.bufferLevel) / this.dsh.duration()  * 100 + "%";
});

Не понимаю как рассчитывать подгруженного уровня буфера. Что за динамические цифры e.bufferLevel?
Их просто добавила к текущему времени и отобразила прогресс буфера. Верно ли сделала?
